# Email Template: text-decoration: none; NOT working

Tags: html, css, html4, email-templates

I am putting a link in email templates and I donot want to underline the link. In Outlook it is working fine but NOT working in Yahoo and Gmail. Sample code is as followed

```
<p> My paragraph
  <b>
    <a style="color: #9B0D25; cursor:pointer; text-decoration: none;" href="abc.com">abc.com</a>
  </b>
</p>
```

I tried `text-decoration: none !important;` but same result. Can any body help me?

Comment: try with this inside `<a>` tag `abc<span>.</span>com`

Comment: Why are you using 2 cursor?

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes do you want to say to use like this: `<a href="abc"> <span> abc.com </span> </a>` ?

Comment: `<a href="abc"> abc<span>.</span>com </a>`

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes It doesn't work !!

Comment: cursor:hand; does not exist what you are looking for is cursor: pointer;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ... I was forwarding email from outlook to yahoo. While sending mail from Outlook, it discards the property `text-decoration: none;`. So when I send email directly to Yahoo, it works !!

Comment: this just save my day today! hahahaha

Comment: Interesting.  And I noticed when forwarding email, gmail also discards border-top-left-radius and border-bottom-left-radius, but not the right side versions of those, nor the general border-radius style.  It seems like an oversight on Google's part.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use paragraphs in HTML email.  Move the style attribute of your anchor tag, to after your href attribute.  If this does not solve your problem you have a larger issue than can be seen from the code you've provided.

Adding the important tag will actually be less effective because Outlook will ignore any styling that is followed by `!important`

If you'd like a template to use, [check this one out.](https://github.com/dcondrey/html-email-boilerplate)

Comment: Well I replace `<p>` with `<h4>` and also put `href` before `style`, but these changes doesn't make it `text-decoration: none;`.